# Convert String and Compare with DF Column Value Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a String of type `val current_dates = "A:2021-04-02,B:2021-04-02,C:2021-04-01,D:2021-04-01"`. Here `A,B,C,D` are id field and their corresponding dates.

Now I have an input dataFrame having multiple records having the id's & date column.

```
val input_df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A","2021-04-01"),("A","2021-04-02"),("B","2021-04-01"),("B","2021-04-02"),("C","2021-04-01"),("C","2021-04-02"),("D","2021-04-01"),("D","2021-04-02"))).toDF("id","create_date")

input_df.show()

+---+-----------+
| id|create_date|
+---+-----------+
|  A| 2021-04-01|
|  A| 2021-04-02|
|  B| 2021-04-01|
|  B| 2021-04-02|
|  C| 2021-04-01|
|  C| 2021-04-02|
|  D| 2021-04-01|
|  D| 2021-04-02|
+---+-----------+
```

Now I want to compare the date value of each record against the corresponding date of each id from the string and derive new date column in the dataFrame.

```
expected_df.select((input_df.columns ++ Array("new_dt")).head, (input_df.columns ++ Array("new_dt")).tail: _*).orderBy("id").show()
+---+-----------+----------+
| id|create_date|    new_dt|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  A| 2021-04-01|2021-04-02|
|  A| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  B| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  B| 2021-04-01|2021-04-02|
|  C| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  C| 2021-04-01|2021-04-01|
|  D| 2021-04-01|2021-04-01|
|  D| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
+---+-----------+----------+
```

Currently I'm converting the string into another dataframe and joining that with input dataframe and deriving the new column in below way.

```
val current_dates_df = sc.parallelize(current_dates.split(",").map(_.split(":")).map{ case Array(a,b) => (a, b) }).toDF("previous_run_id", "previous_run_date")    

current_dates_df.show()   

+---------------+-----------------+
|previous_run_id|previous_run_date|
+---------------+-----------------+
|              A|       2021-04-02|
|              B|       2021-04-02|
|              C|       2021-04-01|
|              D|       2021-04-01|
+---------------+-----------------+ 

val deriveNewDt: UserDefinedFunction = udf[String, String, String]((create_date: String, previous_run_date: String) => {
    val date_format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    val new_dt = {
        if (new SimpleDateFormat(date_format).parse(create_date).after(new SimpleDateFormat(date_format).parse(previous_run_date))) create_date 
        else previous_run_date
    }
    new_dt
})    


val joined_df = input_df.join(current_dates_df, input_df("id") === current_dates_df("previous_run_id"), "left_outer")    

val expected_df = joined_df.withColumn("new_dt", deriveNewDt($"create_date", $"previous_run_date"))    

expected_df.select((input_df.columns ++ Array("new_dt")).head, (input_df.columns ++ Array("new_dt")).tail: _*).show()
```

Is there a better approach to handle the string and achieve the same functionality without converting the string to DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map) to get the date for a given `id`, and use `greatest` to get the later date between the two:

```
val current_dates = "A:2021-04-02,B:2021-04-02,C:2021-04-01,D:2021-04-01"

val result = input_df.withColumn(
    "new_dt", 
    expr(s"greatest(str_to_map('$current_dates, ',', ':')[id], create_date)")
)

result.show
+---+-----------+----------+
| id|create_date|    new_dt|
+---+-----------+----------+
|  A| 2021-04-01|2021-04-02|
|  A| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  B| 2021-04-01|2021-04-02|
|  B| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  C| 2021-04-01|2021-04-01|
|  C| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
|  D| 2021-04-01|2021-04-01|
|  D| 2021-04-02|2021-04-02|
+---+-----------+----------+
```